# Cómo acceder a una API key del archivo .env desde javascript con laravel mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, nodejs, npm, laravel-mix

tengo una api key que [según la documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#environment-variables) debo guardar con el siguiente nombre

```
MIX_GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY=
```

en mi archivo .env para luego acceder a ella mediante

```
let googleGeoCoderApiKey = process.env.MIX_GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY;
```

lo cual estoy haciendo, el mismo IDE me da la sugerencia ya incluso mostrando la API key, esa variable está incluida en un archivo javascript que está minificado por mix de la siguiente manera

```
<script src="{{asset(mix('js/maps/franchise-map.min.js'))}}"></script>
```

y en mi webpack.mix.js lo estoy llamando de la siguiente forma

```
mix.minify([
    'public/js/maps/franchise-map.js',
])
    .version();
```

luego de tener todo esto, hago limpieza de la cache de config y ejecuto el comando `npm run production`, sin embargo, en el navegador obtengo el siguiente error:

> franchise-map.min.js?id=1ed23d100abe226aaceb:1 Uncaught
> ReferenceError: process is not defined
> at franchise-map.min.js?id=1ed23d100abe226aaceb:1:227

cómo puedo corregir este problema?

Comment: Estás seguro de que el path está bien? Generalmente los archivos están en resources/js `mix.minify([
    'public/js/maps/franchise-map.js',
])`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sí, está correcto el path, tengo otros plugins en el mismo script que están funcionando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación oficial que linkeas menciona dos convenciones que aplican:

1. manejar las variables de entorno en un archivo `.env`
2. de entre las definidas en aquel archivo, solamente tomar en cuenta aquellas con prefijo `MIX_`

Los demás supuestos que hiciste no dices de dónde vienen, pero pienso que son erróneos.

**Primero**, mix procesa (en el sentido de transpilar-concatenar-minificar y hacer la sustitución de variables de entorno) desde `resources` y hacia `public`. Esto no está escrito a fuego, pero es [la práctica recomendada](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.1/workflow#step-3-visit-webpackmixjs):

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```

Lo que estás haciendo hoy funciona, anecdóticamente, porque al sufijar (via `.version()`) y usar `minify` (lo cual pone el sufijo `.min`) en rigor la fuente y la salida de la compilación son distintas.   Tienes que pensar que lo que esté en `public` tus visitantes lo pueden abrir via browser. Si necesitas pasar esos scripts por laravel mix significa que no se trata de la salida final, y por tanto no tienen nada que hacer en public.

**Segundo**, comandos como `minify` o `combine` están pensados para cuando tienes un script, plugin, dependencia, etc legacy que es inviable de incorporar a la lógica principal. Por ejemplo, cuando se trata de un montón de globales en un script que no tiene exports de ninguna clase, así que no puedes requerirlo o importar de él.

Mix no intentará procesar ese archivo. Nada de sustitución de variables de entorno, transpilación, tree shaking. Se limita a operaciones que no conllevan parsear el contenido.

En cualquier otro caso, se usa `.js()`, y con ese comando le dejas a mix la responsabilidad de generar un build óptimo. Algo que sabe hacer de sobra.